# Two-level concepts

Tags: c#, design-patterns, layers

I find myself lately implementing the same concept twice, once at a low level and once at a higher level. Let me see if I can explain it...

For example, given the notion of a database, I have one interface (say `IDatabase`) with methods like

```
void AddCompany(Company company);
```

which is what I consider "low level".

However, there are cases where I need to group a few of these calls (say I'm adding both a company and a user). I don't want to pollute the low level interface / implementation with this method, especially since this method basically only groups a few `IDatabase` calls, so I create a new interface. My problem is: what do I call this new interface? `IHighLevelDataAccess` just sounds weird.

I have the same problem with, say, remote access. One interface / implementation for the raw calls (one method maps to one web call) and another one for more complex logic (but mostly still doing remote calls).

Is there a naming convention that is expected / recommended in such cases? A design pattern that eludes me?

Comment: repository and service layers

Comment: Hmm... makes sense. So I would name them IRepository and IDataService?

Comment: IRepository is your IDatabase and WhateverMyServiceDoesService so ShoppingCartService would have all the add basket apply special offer etc

Comment: `IDatabaseMacros` maybe?

Comment: Ahh @Ewan that makes a ton of sense, thank you. @Steve that's also an interesting idea, maybe `IDatabaseTasks`. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I like the base idea. +1. I try to keep the common features of different levels together. But that means you need to use THE SAME interface for these levels, only IMPLEMENTATION will differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Ewan mentioned his comment, you need **Repository Layer** and **Service Layer**.

I also prefer adding **Facade Layer** in **Service Layer**. By this way, you can begin a transaction and can call kind of methods even they are not related.

For example, you have `UserService` and `CompanyService`. Normally, there is not required to create `User` and `Company` same time but you want to do that. So, create a facade `CompanyFacade`, which acts like other services but there is no or less business code, add a method  `CreateCompanyByAddingUser` and begin transaction there.

```cs
public class CompanyFacade
{
    private readonly ICompanyService _companyService;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    private readonly Context _context;

    public CompanyFacade(Context context, ICompanyService companyService, IUserService userService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _companyService = companyService;
        _userService = userService;
    }


    public void CreateCompanyByAddingUser(CompanyAndUserDTO dto)
    {
        using (_context.BeginTransaction())
        {
            _userService.Create(dto.User);
            _companyService.Create(dto.Company);
            _context.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

You can add various methods like that.

Comment: Thanks, "Facade" makes sense.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble you are right. I changed it. You got the point by underscore anyway :) Thanks.